# Inserting across different Partitions within a Partitioned Table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

A general question surrounding Table Partionining. If you're partitioning a table on a Date column with the RANGE being a 12 month period for each.

If you're inserting into prior partition periods, would you expect performance to be slower compared to inserting to the current partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physically each partition is stored a separate data structure, and only the Query Optimizer knows that they make up one logical table.

So you shouldn't expect a significant difference in inserting into one partition or another.

If your table is a clustered index it can be more expensive to insert into the "middle" than the "end", but that's mostly unrelated to whether the clustered index is partitioned.